# FileSystemWatcher does not hear events when application changes files

Tags: powershell, java, events

I have a Powershell Core script that uses `FileSystemWatcher` to listen for changes in a directory recursively. It behaves as expected when a user uses Windows Explorer or a shell to add or modify a file. However, when a Java application adds or modifies a file, the no events are heard. My guess is that shells and Explorer do something that the application is not doing. I found an [old SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/1304153/filesystemwatcher-doesnt-trigger-by-machine-actions#comment2353922_1304153) complaining about the same behavior in a non-java application.

How can I correct this?

I'm using Windows 10 Pro , build 18362, Powershell Version 7.0.0, Java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17

[This is the function I use to create a `FileSystemWatcher` and register it with `Register-ObjectEvent`](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/09/24/changes-to-a-folder-using-powershell.aspx):

```
Function Start-FileSystemWatcher {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [parameter()]
        [string]$Path,
        [parameter()]
        [ValidateSet('Changed', 'Created', 'Deleted', 'Renamed')]
        [string[]]$EventName,
        [parameter()]
        [string]$Filter,
        [parameter()]
        [System.IO.NotifyFilters]$NotifyFilter,
        [parameter()]
        [switch]$Recurse,
        [parameter()]
        [scriptblock]$Action
    )
    $FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Path')) {
        $Path = $PWD
    }
    $FileSystemWatcher.Path = $Path
    If ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Filter')) {
        $FileSystemWatcher.Filter = $Filter
    }

    If ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('NotifyFilter')) {
        $FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter = $NotifyFilter
    }
    If ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Recurse')) {
        $FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $True
    }
    If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('EventName')) {
        $EventName = 'Changed', 'Created', 'Deleted', 'Renamed'
    }
    If (-NOT $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Action')) {
        $Action = {
            Switch ($Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType) {
                'Renamed' {
                    $Object = "{0} was {1} to {2} at {3}" -f $Event.SourceArgs[-1].OldFullPath,
                    $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType,
                    $Event.SourceArgs[-1].FullPath,
                    $Event.TimeGenerated
                }
                Default {
                    $Object = "{0} was {1} at {2}" -f $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath,
                    $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType,
                    $Event.TimeGenerated
                }
            }
            $WriteHostParams = @{
                ForegroundColor = 'Green'
                BackgroundColor = 'Black'
                Object          = $Object
            }
#            Write-Verbose @WriteHostParams
        }
    }
    $ObjectEventParams = @{
        InputObject = $FileSystemWatcher
        Action      = $Action
    }

    ForEach ($Item in $EventName) {
        $ObjectEventParams.EventName = $Item
        $ObjectEventParams.SourceIdentifier = "File.$($Item).$($Path)"
        $Null = Register-ObjectEvent @ObjectEventParams
    }
    New-BurntToastNotification -Text "Registered FileSystemWatchers for $Path"
}
```

Comment: And BTW, I'm currently kind-of working around this registering a timer that fires every 150 seconds, and assumes that files have changed even if they haven't. This is Not Ideal.

Comment: I would bet that this question would find better answers on StackOverflow.. just a hunch.